# How do you extract a bitmap from a TGraphicField?

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I am going nuts.

Here's what I am doing

1. Drop a TClientDataset, a TImage, and a TButton on a form.
2. Set the Clientdataset1.Filename to biolife.xml
3. Double click on the button and add the following code:

   ```
   procedure TForm31.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     BF: TBlobField;
     BS: TStream;
     BM: TBitmap;
   begin
     ClientDataset1.Open;
     ClientDataset1.First;
     BF :=  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Graphic') as TBlobField;
     BS := ClientDataSet1.CreateBlobStream(BF, bmRead);
     BS.Position := 0;
     BM := TBitmap.Create;
     try
       BM.LoadFromStream(BS);
     finally
       BM.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```

Run it.  When I do, I get "Bitmap image is not valid".

Huh?  That data has been a bitmap for years -- what is wrong?

Comment: You're storing bitmap images in your XML file? Odd. Does your dataset object know the encoding of the relevant XML element? If it's been in that file for years, how have you been getting the data until now? Can't you continue doing whatever that was?

Comment: Rob -- Just using Biolife as an example.  It's been part of the sample data with Delphi since Delphi 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Graphics fields are a form of binary large object (BLOB) field where
>   the **data includes a BLOB header** describing the encoding of the
>   graphical value.

"BLOB header" is misleading there, it appears to be a remnant of Paradox storage format for graphic memos.

```
(* from DB *)

{ Paradox graphic BLOB header }
type
  TGraphicHeader = record
    Count: Word;                { Fixed at 1 }
    HType: Word;                { Fixed at $0100 }
    Size: Longint;              { Size not including header }
  end;


procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  HeaderSize = SizeOf(TGraphicHeader);
var
  Field: TGraphicField;
  Stream: TClientBlobStream;
begin
  Field := ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Graphic') as TGraphicField;
  Stream := ClientDataSet1.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmRead) as TClientBlobStream;
  Stream.SaveToFile('dump.bin');            // examine BLOB and see extra bytes preceding BITMAPFILEHEADER
  Assert(Stream.Position = 0);
  Stream.Seek(+HeaderSize, soFromCurrent);  // discard header, it does not contain anything of use anyways
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);

  ClientDataSet1.Next;
end;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you save the `TGraphicField` to a file (using it's `SaveToFile` method) and look at the file with a hex viewer, it is indeed a bitmap. The problem is that there's a blob header at the beginning that describes the filetype. This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TGraphicField), somewhat vaguely. I also found a reference to it in the `TBlobField.GraphicHeader` property description in the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TBlobField.GraphicHeader).

If you set the `Stream.Position` to 8 instead of 0, it correctly reads into a `TBitmap`.

```
BS.Position := 8;
BM.LoadFromStream(BS);
```